# Django: replace columns in ValueQuerySet

Tags: python, django

My django project database is organized like this:

```
Student.objects.values('name', 'schoolId') = [ {'name': 'Bob',   'schoolId': 5},
                                               {'name': 'Alice', 'schoolId': 2} ]
School.objects.values('schoolId', 'name')  = [ {'schoolId': 2,   'name': 'East High'},
                                               {'schoolId': 5,   'name': 'West High'} ]
```

I want to generate a something like this:

```
foo = [ {'name': 'Bob',   'school': 'West High'},
        {'name': 'Alice', 'school': 'East High'} ]
```

Basically it iterates through the first `ValueQuerySet` to replace all `('schoolId', int)` pairs with `('school', schoolNameStr)`. Logically it can achieve this by searching the `schoolId` value in `School` table and returning the corresponding `name` attribute of each entry.

I know and can use a `for` loop and `filter` to do this. But how can I implement it any faster?

Comment: Do you have a relationship in your models between `Student` and `School`? I'm guessing https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#relationships might be a useful read for you

Comment: Sadly no..... I just took over this project from another guy. He didn't use and relationship api provided by Django. Instead, he hard coded to let `Student` have an attribute `schoolId`.....

Comment: That's nice of him. For legacy purposes, can you just keep `schoolId` as an `IntegerField` or whatever it is, then add a new field (`school` maybe?) to the model that's a `ForeignKey`... I guess it should be nullable in the event that Students needn't be assigned to a school yet...

Comment: @JonClements Sure. But I still need to take care of existed data. Any method to tackle this?